# Node.js вставка блоков сайта

Tags: php, html, node.js

В PHP можно вставить в файл блок сайта используя:

```
<?php require_once "block_path.php"?>
```

Я пишу на node.js и мне нужно что-то подобное на `require_once` в node. Как можно это реализовать (на чистом node)?

Comment: Нужна конкретика. Под ноду десяток фреймворков, ещё больше шаблонизаторов и это не считая самописных велосипедов

Comment: @AlexeyTen чисто node

Comment: Ну как напишите так и будет. Учтите, что в отличии от пхп сервер на ноде это долгоживущий процесс